# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget 1.8 click handler discrepancy

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, handler, multi-select

I have an instance of Eric Hynd's [multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) on my site.

In it's click handler, I have an alert telling me how many checkboxes are selected-

```
alert($(this).multiselect("getChecked").length
```

Suppose the widget starts off with no checkboxes checked. If I check one, the alert gives me "1", meaning that the checkbox is already selected when the click handler is hit.

Now say that instead of explicitly clicking, I do what Eric Hynds suggests to fake a click-

```
$("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox:eq(2)").trigger("click");
```

(I select the checkbox with the value of 2 here just for demonstration purposes.) The alert here gives me 0.

I haven't been able to figure out why there is this discrepancy and its causing issues when I'm trying to limit the number of checkboxes a user can select. They are able to check checkboxes not only by clicking them but also by clicking things outside the widget, which is why I have to fake clicks on the actual checkboxes.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `:checkbox:eq(2)` does not select the checkbox with value 2, it selects the third checkbox in the array of matched elements: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: that detail is irrelevant and was indeed my mistake in typing up the question quickly

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) says:

> ... the native click event must be used (trigger('click') will not work) due to this bug in jQuery’s core ...

so, something like this I think:

```
$("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox:eq(2)").each(function(){  
    this.click(); 
});
```